# Selenium proxy IP(change) doesnt work Firefox, python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

I have a problem with adding a proxy to my firefox selenium browser.
I use the code below and change the HTTP ip and port number that I both got from proxy-list.download. When I execute the program and go to whatmyip.org it shows my recent ip without a proxy.

I already tried multiple stackoverflow threads but none of them helped me.
Info: Firefox 66.0.1 (64-bits), using Geckodriver, python and selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", "1.20.217.221")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", 8080)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/")
```